# Issues with echoing

Tags: php

Currently I have this code displayed below, which is suppose to display the advertisement when the users country is = to US but id does not work properly.

```
$ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
$details = json_decode(file_get_contents("http://ipinfo.io/{$ip}/json"));
$location = $details->country;
$details->country;

    if($location == 'CA') {

    echo '<script type="text/javascript">';
    echo "<!-- window['pubs_ad_padid']"; echo '= "1005";';
    echo "window['pubs_ad_subid'] = ''; //Insert value to pass through your sub id //-->";
    echo "var se = document.createElement('script');";
    echo 'se.type = "text/javascript";';
    echo "se.src = (document.location.protocol ==="; echo ' "https:" ? "https:" : "http:") + "//d.example.com/js/pub.js";';
    echo "document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(se);";
    echo "</script>";
}
```

Here's the normal code without all the echo jazz included.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
window['pubs_ad_padid'] = "1005";
window['pubs_ad_subid'] = ''; //Insert value to pass through your sub id
//-->
var se = document.createElement('script');
se.type = "text/javascript";
se.src = (document.location.protocol === "https:" ? "https:" : "http:") + "//d.example.com/js/pub.js";
document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(se);
</script>
```

Comment: Why are you trying to generate your entire JS block from the PHP?  You should code the JS on the page, and only use PHP to echo the vars that you need.

Comment: @durbnpoisn I tried, didn't work for some reason.. so I went with this approach

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried it like this:

```
<?php
if($location == 'CA') {
?>
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
window['pubs_ad_padid'] = "1005";
window['pubs_ad_subid'] = ''; //Insert value to pass through your sub id
//-->
var se = document.createElement('script');
se.type = "text/javascript";
se.src = (document.location.protocol === "https:" ? "https:" : "http:") + "//d.example.com/js/pub.js";
document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(se);
</script>
<?>}</?>
```

That's the basics of it.  What that will do is only echo that Script if the condition is met.  And it also allows you to much more easily add another PHP echo inside there, if need be.  And you don't have to fiddle around with all those quotes.  Which is likely what your problem is.